# python recipe for temporarily modifying dict on the fly

Tags: python

I see this pattern in some code that i'm writing

```
e = {...} # a dictionary
e["table"] = "users"
e["timestamp"] = time.time()
queue.push(e)
del e["table"]
del e["timestamp"]
[...]
e["table"] = "events"
queue2.push(e)
del e["table"]
# etc..
```

I'm demultiplexing an event over some queues but each queue has a slightly different format. I've started doing this:

```
queue.push( dict(e.items() + [("table":"users"), ("timestamp", time.time())]) )
```

but it looks ugly and it kind of slows down the code. What else can i do?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `queue.push` only needs read access, you could try something like this:

```
class MergedDicts(dict):
    def __init__(self, *dicts, **kw):
        self.dicts = dicts + (kw,)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        for d in self.dicts:
            if key in d: return d[key]
        raise KeyError(key)
```

This would give you a dictionary returning items from both sources, but avoid the overhead of building another actual copy from the originals (you may need to implement more than just `__getitem__` though, depending on what `push` needs).

Usage:

```
other = {"table": "users", "timestamp": time.time()}
queue.push(MergedDicts(e, other))
```

or:

```
queue.push(MergedDicts(e, table="users", timestamp=time.time()))
```

Comment: nice, clean solution. The only possible downside I see is that it will make accessing the elements a bit slower. OTOH, this might perform better if there aren't many accesses and the number of fields to update is large

Comment: Doesn't `MergeDicts` need to call its superclass in its own `__init__()`? Otherwise it's not a properly initialized subclass...

Comment: `MergedDicts` doesn't seem to take advantage of the fact that it is itself a `dict`; all the work is done by the new `dicts` attribute.

Comment: @martineau Only if I want to extend the original functionality, and in this case I don't because I'm not actually populating the dictionary directly (which is what `__init__` does). You might argue that I shouldn't have inherited `dict` in the first place though.

Comment: IMHO, no, you shouldn't have subclassed `dict`, since at best it's misleading, but in this case your implementation is incorrect, too. Did you even test the code in your answer?

Comment: @martineau My implementation is not incorrect. It is possibly incomplete, though, as I mentioned. And yes, I did test it. Perhaps *you* should have tested it as well before downvoting. Here you go: http://ideone.com/BVDdx7

Comment: It may work in the limited way shown in the your link, but does it support all `dict` operations? According the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) it should. Since you never call the base class constructor you can't be sure of that and doing so would be a big job, which is why I didn't do your work for you. Fixing your code would be easy and make doing such extensive testing unnecessary -- so why don't you just do that (or better yet, don't derive the class from `dict`)?

Comment: @martineau I think I've made it clear enough in both my answer and my comments that the above code can be expanded upon as needed. Your earlier comment claimed that it was untested and broken, which it isn't. Are you telling me now that you're downvoting the answer simply because of lack of stringent adherence to OOP philosophy in a code stub? Really?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new dictionary with the new fields you want and use `dict.update` on it with the base fields

```
e = {...} # a dictionary
d={"table":"users", "timestamp":time.time()}
d.update(e)
queue.push(d)
```

---

You could also create a new dict with fields as a list:

```
e = {...} # a dictionary
queue.push( e.items() + [("table","users"), ("timestamp",time.time())] )
```

---

If you do this a lot on large dictionaries, and don't want to create a copy, you can use a [Context Manager](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) that modifies the dictionary temporarily, automating what you're doing right now.

---

Another option, instead of the context manager, is performing the modification in a function, passing the operations you want to do as a function:

```
def modify_dict_and_call( d, newfields, f):
    for k,v in newfields.items():
        d[k]=v
    f(d)
    for k in newfields:
        del d[k]

e = {...} # a dictionary
modify_dict_and_call( e, {"table":"users", "timestamp":time.time()}, queue.push )
```

Answer (score 1):

If the number of modifications to the dictionary are relatively small compared to the size of the dictionary itself, you can avoid making a copy of it each time by creating a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html?highlight=contextmanager#contextlib.contextmanager) function and using it as shown. This will insure that any changes made to the dictionary are temporary, even if an exception is thrown while using it inside the block.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def contextdict(adict, **kwargs):
    # modify dictionary
    changed = {}
    added = []
    for key in kwargs:
        if key in adict:
            changed[key] = adict[key]
        else:
            added.append(key)
        adict[key] = kwargs[key]
    yield adict
    # restore dictionary
    adict.update(changed)
    for key in added:
        del adict[key]

e = dict(...)  # some dictionary

with contextdict(e, table="users", timestamp=time.time()) as context:
    queue.push(context)
with contextdict(e, table="events") as context:
    queue.push(context)

# e will be unchanged at this point
```

Answer (score 0):

If you initially define `e` with only those keys that are common to each use case, you can use the `mock` library. `mock.patch.dict` allows you to temporarily add keys to a dictionary (for the duration of the `with` statement), although you cannot temporarily *remove* keys.

```
e = { ... }
with mock.patch.dict(e, table="users", timestamp=time.time()):
    queue.push(e)

with mock.patch.dict(e, table="events"):
    queue2.push(e)
```

`mock` is a third-party module for Python 2.x and prior to Python 3.4, where it was added to the standard library as `unittest.mock`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is might be covered with the next code:

```
a = {'val': 2, 'val2': -5, "name": 'Vladimir'}
b = {"asdf": 1, "b2": 2}
queue.push( dict( **a, **b) )
```